# Using Fonts in a resource file

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-fonts

When I use a custom font for my `TextView`, I do this :

```
textView.typeface = resources.getFont(R.font.dancing_script)
```

whereas `R.font.dancing_script` references a `dancing_script.tff` file in `res/font` folder of my project.

Now, Android Studio tells me that the call to `getFont()` requires `minSdkVersion` of `26`.
What should I do when I have a project with `minSdkVersion < 26` ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically fonts are supported in 2 ways.

First

Via assets folder, In this you package font with the apk, so it increases apk size.

Second

Via resource folder, in this, you add font XML file, which download font post-installation, so it does not increase app download size.
Downloadable fonts are supported since android 26, for older versions support you need to use support library.
read below link for that
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts